# Kernel of polynomial subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

**Problem**

Let $n > 1$ denote a natural number, and let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ denote a scalar.

We now define:

$$V = \{p\in P_n(\mathbb{R}) : p(\alpha)=0\}$$

Calculate the dimension of $V$; $\dim(V)$

**My attempt**

I have tried different things, but it all resulted in more confusion, but I think I need to solve this equation:

$$\dim(V)  = \dim(\ker(L)) + \dim(L(V ))$$

$$\ker(L) = Ax = 0 $$

Where $A$ is the matrixrepresentation of all polynomials in V.
I feel like the $\dim(\ker(L))$ here should be $0$ dimensional since $RREF(A)$ would contain $n$ pivots and $n$ colums.

And $\dim(L(V ))$ I unfortunately have no clue about how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\;V=\ker\phi\;$ , with

$$\phi:V\to\Bbb R\;\;,\;\;\phi(p(x)):=p(\alpha)$$